# How to set this icon for the web page?

Tags: web, icons

I would like to know what is this little icon called? And how to set the icon for that? Thanks.[image]

Answer (score 38, accepted):

View source on SO, and you will see this `link` element:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico">
```

Comment: This works to change the tab icon, but it never changes my URI bar (as Ted Wong's picture above).  Are the tab and URI icons not related?  Are they not suppose to be set together with your <link ...> tag?  Tried in both Chrome and Firefox, same results.

Comment: Ah, you can find a table of supported favicon locations here:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon#Use_of_favicon

Comment: @Jeach that's an older browser. (looks like an old version of safari) It may put the favicons in the URI bar, instead of the tabs. (which it doesn't even appear to have...)

Answer (score 14):

It's called the icon of your web-page. To include this in page use

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
```

you insert this tag with in `head` tag and can be easily created using  `ms paint`

Comment: **mspaint** cannot save .ico files, how did you do that ?

Answer (score 3):

Probably you will be suffering after changing the favicon more than once, just keep that in mind; after every change of ico file change the `href="favicon.ico?v=#` -# means count of change-.